# Pyqt5 qthread + signal not working + gui freeze

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I am trying to make a mailbox checker with `imap` lib, it work pretty fine with python, queue and multithread without gui.

But when I try to put a gui, every fonction i made, make the gui freeze until finish .

I tried many thing from various doc(add qthread, signal, cursorr etcc) and tutorials none worked for me .

Can someone help me to understand how to set or append a text to a QtextEdit while running a function coz it work only after finish .

Here is my code :

```
class Checker(QtCore.QThread):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, lignesmailtocheck):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.lignesmailtocheck = lignesmailtocheck

    def run(self):
            lignemailtocheck = self.lignesmailtocheck.strip()                        
            maillo, passo = lignemailtocheck.split(":",1)
            debmail, finmail = maillo.split("@",1)
            setimap =["oultook.com:imap-mail.outlook.com", "gmail.com:imap.gmail.com"]
            for lignesimaptocheck in sorted(setimap):
                    ligneimaptocheck = lignesimaptocheck.strip()
                    fai, imap = ligneimaptocheck.split(":",1)                                
                    if finmail == fai:
                            passo0 = passo.rstrip()
                            try :
                                    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap)
                                    mail.login(maillo, passo)
                                    mailboxok = open("MailBoxOk.txt", "a+", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
                                    mailboxok.write(maillo+":"+passo+"\n")
                                    mailboxok.close()
                                    totaly = maillo+":"+passo0+":"+imap                                
                                    print(maillo+":"+passo+"\n")

                                    self.send_text.emit(totaly)
                                    time.sleep(1)
                            except imaplib.IMAP4.error:                          
                                           print ("LOGIN FAILED!!! ")
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 210, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.gogogo)

        self.openliste = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Form)
        self.openliste.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 71, 21))
        self.openliste.setObjectName("openliste")

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 50, 201, 121))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Form)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 260, 381, 23))
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
        self.openliste.setText(_translate("Form", "..."))

    def gogogo(self):

        mailtocheck = open('File/toCheck.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').readlines()        
        setmailtocheck = set(mailtocheck)
        for lignesmailtocheck in sorted(setmailtocheck):
            checker = Checker(lignesmailtocheck)

            thread = QThread()
            checker.moveToThread(thread)
            # connections after move so cross-thread:
            thread.started.connect(checker.run)
            checker.signal.connect(self.checkedok)
            thread.start()

    def checkedok(self, data):
        print(data)
        self.textEdit.append(data)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You must describe the steps to reproduce the problem. When I run this (after deleting a couple of lines of imports), and click the pushbutton, I see YY printed to console but no freeze. Please post the code that causes the issue, with steps to get freeze, and we can help you fix that.

Comment: sorry for the import i tryed so much various thing to make it work....the step are : after click on the push button, the programme get the login in the file  'File/toCheck.txt' the format is email:pass and the login are send to the qtreah. In the thread the login are tryed with imap and if the login is ok the QtextEdit print the valid login . if you try with 2-3 email:pass in the file u don't have the time to see it don't work correctly but if you try with a lot the gui freeze and the QtextEdit print only when finished

Comment: How many threads are you creating in that loop? The Python GIL prevents threads from executing concurrently, and it's possible that having a large number of threads is just decreasing the time spent in the main thread (redrawing the GUI) to the point where it looks like it is frozen and not updating.

Comment: in this code i send 1 thread by line in the file .txt . But it can have 2, 10, 100 or 1000  the gui freeze anyways . I first try to make the same with python thread and queue but i issue the same problems as with Qthread . The gui freeze even if the signal is emit  and gui update only when finish. Plz tell me what i do wrong .

Comment: I recommend deriving Checker thread from QObject and creating a QThread object, and checker.moveTo(thread).

Comment: i find this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt) about move to thread but i can't make this working in my gui it still freeze until the end...can you tell me more about this

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Since there are often questions about using `QThread` in PyQt, similar to yours, here is an example that shows how to correctly use threads in PyQt. I'm hoping it can be useful as a goto-answer for similar questions so I spent a bit more time than usual preparing this.

The example creates a number of worker objects that execute in non-main threads and communicate with the main (ie GUI) thread via Qt's asynchronous signals.

```
import time
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


def trap_exc_during_debug(*args):
    # when app raises uncaught exception, print info
    print(args)


# install exception hook: without this, uncaught exception would cause application to exit
sys.excepthook = trap_exc_during_debug


class Worker(QObject):
    """
    Must derive from QObject in order to emit signals, connect slots to other signals, and operate in a QThread.
    """

    sig_step = pyqtSignal(int, str)  # worker id, step description: emitted every step through work() loop
    sig_done = pyqtSignal(int)  # worker id: emitted at end of work()
    sig_msg = pyqtSignal(str)  # message to be shown to user

    def __init__(self, id: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.__id = id
        self.__abort = False

    @pyqtSlot()
    def work(self):
        """
        Pretend this worker method does work that takes a long time. During this time, the thread's
        event loop is blocked, except if the application's processEvents() is called: this gives every
        thread (incl. main) a chance to process events, which in this sample means processing signals
        received from GUI (such as abort).
        """
        thread_name = QThread.currentThread().objectName()
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())  # cast to int() is necessary
        self.sig_msg.emit('Running worker #{} from thread "{}" (#{})'.format(self.__id, thread_name, thread_id))

        for step in range(100):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.sig_step.emit(self.__id, 'step ' + str(step))

            # check if we need to abort the loop; need to process events to receive signals;
            app.processEvents()  # this could cause change to self.__abort
            if self.__abort:
                # note that "step" value will not necessarily be same for every thread
                self.sig_msg.emit('Worker #{} aborting work at step {}'.format(self.__id, step))
                break

        self.sig_done.emit(self.__id)

    def abort(self):
        self.sig_msg.emit('Worker #{} notified to abort'.format(self.__id))
        self.__abort = True


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    NUM_THREADS = 5

    # sig_start = pyqtSignal()  # needed only due to PyCharm debugger bug (!)
    sig_abort_workers = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Thread Example")
        form_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(form_layout)
        self.resize(400, 800)

        self.button_start_threads = QPushButton()
        self.button_start_threads.clicked.connect(self.start_threads)
        self.button_start_threads.setText("Start {} threads".format(self.NUM_THREADS))
        form_layout.addWidget(self.button_start_threads)

        self.button_stop_threads = QPushButton()
        self.button_stop_threads.clicked.connect(self.abort_workers)
        self.button_stop_threads.setText("Stop threads")
        self.button_stop_threads.setDisabled(True)
        form_layout.addWidget(self.button_stop_threads)

        self.log = QTextEdit()
        form_layout.addWidget(self.log)

        self.progress = QTextEdit()
        form_layout.addWidget(self.progress)

        QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('main')  # threads can be named, useful for log output
        self.__workers_done = None
        self.__threads = None

    def start_threads(self):
        self.log.append('starting {} threads'.format(self.NUM_THREADS))
        self.button_start_threads.setDisabled(True)
        self.button_stop_threads.setEnabled(True)

        self.__workers_done = 0
        self.__threads = []
        for idx in range(self.NUM_THREADS):
            worker = Worker(idx)
            thread = QThread()
            thread.setObjectName('thread_' + str(idx))
            self.__threads.append((thread, worker))  # need to store worker too otherwise will be gc'd
            worker.moveToThread(thread)

            # get progress messages from worker:
            worker.sig_step.connect(self.on_worker_step)
            worker.sig_done.connect(self.on_worker_done)
            worker.sig_msg.connect(self.log.append)

            # control worker:
            self.sig_abort_workers.connect(worker.abort)

            # get read to start worker:
            # self.sig_start.connect(worker.work)  # needed due to PyCharm debugger bug (!); comment out next line
            thread.started.connect(worker.work)
            thread.start()  # this will emit 'started' and start thread's event loop

        # self.sig_start.emit()  # needed due to PyCharm debugger bug (!)

    @pyqtSlot(int, str)
    def on_worker_step(self, worker_id: int, data: str):
        self.log.append('Worker #{}: {}'.format(worker_id, data))
        self.progress.append('{}: {}'.format(worker_id, data))

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_worker_done(self, worker_id):
        self.log.append('worker #{} done'.format(worker_id))
        self.progress.append('-- Worker {} DONE'.format(worker_id))
        self.__workers_done += 1
        if self.__workers_done == self.NUM_THREADS:
            self.log.append('No more workers active')
            self.button_start_threads.setEnabled(True)
            self.button_stop_threads.setDisabled(True)
            # self.__threads = None

    @pyqtSlot()
    def abort_workers(self):
        self.sig_abort_workers.emit()
        self.log.append('Asking each worker to abort')
        for thread, worker in self.__threads:  # note nice unpacking by Python, avoids indexing
            thread.quit()  # this will quit **as soon as thread event loop unblocks**
            thread.wait()  # <- so you need to wait for it to *actually* quit

        # even though threads have exited, there may still be messages on the main thread's
        # queue (messages that threads emitted before the abort):
        self.log.append('All threads exited')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    form = MyWidget()
    form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The main concepts necessary to understand multi-thread programming in PyQt are the following:

- Qt threads have their own event loop (specific to each thread). The main thread, aka the GUI thread, is also a `QThread`, and its event loop is managed by that thread.
- Signals between threads are transmitted (asynchronously) via the receiving thread's event loop. Hence responsiveness of GUI or any thread = ability to process events. E.g., if a thread is busy in a function loop, it can't process events, so it won't respond to signals from the GUI until the function returns.
- If a worker object (method) in a thread may have to change its course of action based on signals from the GUI (say, to interrupt a loop or a wait), it  must call `processEvents()` on the `QApplication` instance. This will allow the QThread to process events, and hence to call slots in response to async signals from the GUI. Note that `QApplication.instance().processEvents()` seems to call `processEvents()` on every thread, if this is not desired then `QThread.currentThread().processEvents()` is a valid alternative.
- A call to `QThread.quit()` does not immediately quit its event loop: it must wait for currently executing slot (if any) to return. Hence once a thread is told to quit, you must wait() on it. So aborting a worker thread usually involves signaling it (via a custom signal) to stop whatever it is doing: this requires a custom signal on a GUI object, a connection of that signal to a worker slot, and worker work method must call thread's `processEvents()` to allow the emitted signal to reach the slot while doing work.

Comment: this one is exactly what i was needing to understand that's you

Comment: Has anyone figured out why this example crashes if you try to run the threads again after its first completion?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the pycharm debugger bug you reference in comments? I have wasted a significant amount of time over the last few days learning pyqt5 and multithreading because of the unpredictable behavior within pycharm's debugger. I have experienced what you reference in the comments where a slot connected to a thread's start signal does not called when running under the pycharm debugger. Is there a ticket with Jetbrains on this? I made another SO question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43923706/3154588, for further discussion of this problem.

Comment: I name you Freddy McThread, god of PyQt threads ! Seriously, thanks for the extensive example, it's just what I needed.

Comment: My problem here was not storing the worker, thus invoking garbage collection; thanks for clarifying that

Comment: Glad it has been useful

Comment: Zach, the problem is that on the second run, the start_threads method loses the reference to the previous list of threads when it calls self.__threads = []. The solution to this is to create the empty list only if it has nothing stored previously: if not self.__threads: self.__threads = []

Comment: @ZachSchulze After the threads finish 100 steps, the threads' event loops are still running. Then as Sergio said, `self.__threads = []` makes the threads get garbage collected, which gets an error if the threads are still running. If you want to finish these threads so you can GC them, you must call `thread.quit()` and `thread.wait()` on them; for example, you might do this at the end of `on_worker_done()`. If you want to just add 5 more threads alongside the existing ones, then one solution is what Sergio proposed.

Comment: `QThread.currentThread().processEvents()` gives `QThread` object has no attribute 'processEvents'

Comment: This again assumes that the process that takes long is a simple loop that one can tap into. What if the process that takes long is simply a single function with no loops (or at least, none that you can modify) and you want to be able to abort that process from within the application (like a `KeyboardInterrupt`)?

Comment: Just a little note: processEvents() is a static method so you can also call `QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()` instead of `app.processEvents()` if someone wonders.

Comment: In case it's not immediately obvious, to answer Zach's question as S. Kirby describes, within `on_worker_done`, before the `if`, put `thread, worker = self.__threads[worker_id]; thread.quit(); thread.wait()` (replace the ';' with newlines).

Answer (score 2):

I can't test because setimap is not available on my system. I renamed `CheckerThread` to `Checker` since it is no longer a thread (it just "lives" in a thread):

```
class Checker(QtCore.QObject):
```

Then just replace the contents of the loop in `gogogo(self)` with this:

```
for lignesmailtocheck in sorted(setmailtocheck):
    checker = Checker(lignesmailtocheck)

    thread = QThread()
    checker.moveToThread(thread)
    # connections after move so cross-thread:
    thread.started.connect(checker.run)
    checker.signal.connect(self.checkedok)
    thread.start()

    self.threads.append(thread)
```

It is almost always a good idea to decorate slots with `pyqtSlot` so both `run` and `checkedok` should be thus decorated.

The [SO answer about Qt threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033971/qt-thread-with-movetothread) is quite handy to remind yourself of details (note however that it uses old-style connections -- you have to translate C++ `connect( sender, SIGNAL(sig), receiver, SLOT(slot));` to PyQt5 `sender.sig.connect(receiver.slot)`).

Comment: thank you for all this informations, they help me to understand

Comment: it seem to work but i still get an error that i can't handle, now the error is : "pyqt qthread destroyed while thread is still running"

Comment: In the file fonc there is a set with imap like : setimap = ["oultook.com:imap-mail.outlook.com",    "gmail.com:imap.gmail.com"]

Comment: I have updated my answer although without seeing your code it is difficult to tell what problem is, and obviously I can't run it because the files don't exist. I recommend creating a new question and post an example that runs standalone (no file creation, do everything in memory). Once that works, I can modify this answer so you can close this question.

Comment: I edit my post, clean the code  as i can and change the `from fonc import * `, like this you have the set in the code, for the file in /File/toCheck.txt,  it contain my login in this format : email:pass, i can't post my login, but you can try to connect with your login on hotmail or gmail , for do this create the new folder in the same directory of my code, rename it to "File" , and create a new texte file .txt, remane the .txt to "toCheck.txt".Finaly insert your login on hotmail or gmail in the format email:pass on each lines . Hope this will help you to identify the problem

Comment: Sorry but I don't have time to fiddle with login and folders. You should be able to patch your code so that login is not necessary, such as by directly defining the data that gmail etc would return and putting a sleep or such to pretend this takes time. Basically, an [minimally self-contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i just don't want to give to all reader the login to all of my maibox, and in more as i say in the first line of the post "I am trying to make a mailbox checker " so checker mean to know if password is correct or not if correct the code append to the textEdit but any of my try fail, with my initial code it append only when the fonction is finished, and with your i get this error : qthread destroyed while thread is still running

Comment: i finaly find other solution with pyside thank you for your help

Comment: Good to hear. You should post an answer for benefit of all.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer but it is a technique that can solve similar problems.

The problem is clear. The GUI freezes because its thread has to do another job.
An abstracted(from the PyQt point) solution is given below:

1. Create a class inheriting from threading.Thread which will be the worker.
2. Pass to the constructor a queue(queue.Queue) as a means of communication.
3. You can start the worker thread from the GUI thread and pass messages by using the queue.
4. To make the GUI thread read the messages, create a QTimer with interval of your choice and register a callback function. In the callback function read the queue.

Example Code:

```
class Worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().init()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
         # Your code that uses self.queue.put(object)

class Gui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = Qtimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(milliseconds)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.read_data)


    def start_worker(self):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

        thr = Worker(self.queue)

        thr.start()


    def read_data(self):
        data = self.queue.get()
```

self.timer.timeout.connect registers the callback function.

Comment: Couldn't get the QTimer working, but this solution is definitely the simplest and works quite fine.

Comment: While simple, this ad-hoc solution definitely does *not* behave as expected in the general case. The fact that it mildly works at all is a testament to the thread-safe `queue.Queue` class. Most standard Python classes and objects are *not* thread-safe; this includes primitive scalars (e.g., `bool`, `int`, `str`). Multithreaded Qt applications leveraging low-level Python primitives rather than high-level Qt abstractions (e.g., `QThread`, `QConcurrent`) are absolutely **doing it wrong.** Instead, you should *always* use signal-slot connections on `QObject`-based workers moved into a `QThread`.