# PyQt5 window keeps freezing although using threads

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, freeze

in order to get my co-workers more security aware and show them how easy it is to crack a password with even the simplest of coding, I wrote a simple programm that is just brute-force checking every possible combination.
In order to give them a little tool to play around I wanted to wrap it inside a small pyqt application.
In Spyder and on console the cracking programm runs just fine even with longer passwords. Yet, when using PyQT5 it freezes when I try and test longer passwords. E.g. on a console when cracking abcd34 it takes about 1:30mins, using PyQt even after 10mins nothing has happened.
I followed this post ([Pyqt5 qthread + signal not working + gui freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526832/pyqt5-qthread-signal-not-working-gui-freeze/41605909#41605909)) and used threads but it just keeps freezing. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Anja

This is my Code:

```
import itertools
import string
import datetime as dt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLineEdit


def trap_exc_during_debug(*args):
    # when app raises uncaught exception, print info
    print(args)


# install exception hook: without this, uncaught exception would cause application to exit
sys.excepthook = trap_exc_during_debug


class Worker(QObject):
    """
    Must derive from QObject in order to emit signals, connect slots to other signals, and operate in a QThread.
    """

    sig_done = pyqtSignal(int)  # worker id: emitted at end of work()
    sig_msg = pyqtSignal(str)  # message to be shown to user

    def __init__(self, id: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.__id = id
        self.__abort = False

    @pyqtSlot()
    def work(self, value):
        """
        Pretend this worker method does work that takes a long time. During this time, the thread's
        event loop is blocked, except if the application's processEvents() is called: this gives every
        thread (incl. main) a chance to process events, which in this sample means processing signals
        received from GUI (such as abort).
        """
        thread_name = QThread.currentThread().objectName()
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())  # cast to int() is necessary
        self.sig_msg.emit('Starting brute force password cracking.\n\n')

        time1 = dt.datetime.now()
        special = "@%-*,'&`._!#$§äöü?=+:;/\[]{}()"
        chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + special
        attempts = 0

        for password_length in range(1, 10):
            for guess in itertools.product(chars, repeat=password_length):
                attempts += 1
                guess = ''.join(guess)
                if guess == value: #self.freetextle.text():
                    time2 = (dt.datetime.now() - time1)
                    self.sig_done.emit(self.__id)
                    return self.sig_msg.emit('Password is {} and it was found in {} guesses, which took me {} seconds'.format(guess, attempts, time2))

        # check if we need to abort the loop; need to process events to receive signals;
        app.processEvents()  # this could cause change to self.__abort
        if self.__abort:
            # note that "step" value will not necessarily be same for every thread
            self.sig_msg.emit('aborting')

        self.sig_done.emit(self.__id)

    def abort(self):
        self.sig_msg.emit('notified to abort')
        self.__abort = True


class MyWidget(QWidget):

    # sig_start = pyqtSignal()  # needed only due to PyCharm debugger bug (!)
    sig_abort_workers = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Simple password cracker")
        form_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(form_layout)
        self.resize(400, 400)

        self.button_start_threads = QPushButton()
        self.button_start_threads.clicked.connect(self.start_threads)
        self.button_start_threads.setText("Start")
        form_layout.addWidget(self.button_start_threads)

        # create the input field
        self.freetextle = QLineEdit()
        self.freetextle.setObjectName("password")
        self.freetextle.setText("Enter a password to check")
        form_layout.addWidget(self.freetextle)

        self.log = QTextEdit()
        form_layout.addWidget(self.log)

        QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('main')  # threads can be named, useful for log output
        self.__workers_done = None
        self.__threads = None

    def start_threads(self):
        #self.log.append('starting threads')
        self.button_start_threads.setDisabled(True)

        self.__workers_done = 0
        self.__threads = []
        worker = Worker(1)
        thread = QThread()
        thread.setObjectName('thread_1')# + str(idx))
        self.__threads.append((thread, worker))  # need to store worker too otherwise will be gc'd
        worker.moveToThread(thread)

        # get progress messages from worker:
        worker.sig_step.connect(self.on_worker_step)
        worker.sig_done.connect(self.on_worker_done)
        worker.sig_msg.connect(self.log.append)

        # control worker:
        self.sig_abort_workers.connect(worker.abort)

        # get read to start worker:
        # self.sig_start.connect(worker.work)  # needed due to PyCharm debugger bug (!); comment out next line
        thread.started.connect(worker.work(self.freetextle.text()))
        thread.start()  # this will emit 'started' and start thread's event loop

        # self.sig_start.emit()  # needed due to PyCharm debugger bug (!)

    @pyqtSlot(int, str)
    def on_worker_step(self, worker_id: int, data: str):
        self.log.append('Worker #{}: {}'.format(worker_id, data))

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_worker_done(self, worker_id):
        self.log.append('done')
        self.__workers_done += 1
        #if self.__workers_done == 1:
        #    self.log.append('No more workers active')
        self.button_start_threads.setEnabled(True)
            # self.__threads = None

    @pyqtSlot()
    def abort_workers(self):
        self.sig_abort_workers.emit()
        self.log.append('Asking to abort')
        for thread, worker in self.__threads:  # note nice unpacking by Python, avoids indexing
            thread.quit()  # this will quit **as soon as thread event loop unblocks**
            thread.wait()  # <- so you need to wait for it to *actually* quit

        # even though threads have exited, there may still be messages on the main thread's
        # queue (messages that threads emitted before the abort):
        self.log.append('All threads exited')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    form = MyWidget()
    form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `worker.sig_step.connect(self.on_worker_step)`  What is `sig_step`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in thread.started.connect. There you INVOKE the work method by passing a parameter, instead of just making a signal/slot connection.

Given that started has no arguments, you can’t possible pass arguments to a slot via this connection. So you need pass the text as argument to workers constructor. And use it in the Worker as member.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, now it's working :-)

Comment: Then I would like to encourage you to flag my post as answer ;)