# Progressbar dialog is not displaying but the thread is still running in background

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I want the progressbar dialog should display the progress when the start button is pressed. The progressbar will display the progress of two for loops calculationg some values. I have a main module and a progressbar module. Now, the class in MyThread module is running on click of start button but the Progress is not being displayed in the progressbar dialog. But the progressbar dialog is empty !!!

### ** Main Module

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, 
QPushButton, QProgressDialog
from TEST_PROGRESSBAR import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Create a QPushButton
        self.btn_start_calculation = QPushButton("Start Calculation")
        self.btn_start_calculation.clicked.connect(self.run_calculator)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_start_calculation)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')

    def run_calculator(self):
        # Create a calculator with some loop ranges
        calculator = MyThread([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 54, 55, 322])

        # Start the calculation
        calculator.run()

        # calculator.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

### ** Progressbar Module

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QProgressDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

class MyThread(QThread):
    # Define a signal to update the progress bar
    update_progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, w1, w2):
        super().__init__()
        self.w1 = w1  # The first list
        self.w2 = w2  # The second list
        self.total = len(w1) + len(w2)  # The total number of iterations
        self.count = 0  # The current count
        self.is_running = True  # Flag to indicate if the thread should keep running

    def run(self):

        # Create a QProgressDialog
        progress_dialog = QProgressDialog("Calculating...", "Cancel", 0, 100, None)
        progress_dialog.setWindowTitle("Progress")
        progress_dialog.setModal(True)

        # Set the fixed size of the progress dialog (width, height)
        progress_dialog.setFixedSize(700, 200)

        progress_dialog.show()

        # Iterate over the first list and emit the signal with the percentage
        for i in range(len(self.w1)):
            # Check if the thread should stop
            if not self.is_running:
                break
        
            print(i * 1234567)  # Do some calculation
            self.count += 1  # Increment the count
            self.update_progress.emit(int(self.count / self.total * 100))  # Emit the signal
            self.sleep(1)  # Simulate some work
            print('**loop1')

        # Iterate over the second list and emit the signal with the percentage
        for i in range(len(self.w2)):
            # Check if the thread should stop
            if not self.is_running:
                break

            print(i * 1234567)  # Do some calculation
            self.count += 1  # Increment the count
            self.update_progress.emit(int(self.count / self.total * 100))  # Emit the signal
            self.sleep(1)  # Simulate some work
            print('**loop2')

        ### Close the progress dialog when the loop is finished
        progress_dialog.close()

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False

def clean_up():
    # Delete the thread and the dialog objects
    global thread, dialog
    thread.deleteLater()
    dialog.deleteLater()
```

Comment: Just read some good [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41605909/14956120) already provided on stackoverflow. Also, though I admit it's a little difficult to catch an eye of it when you're a new user, the site has a search bar. The correct answer you're seeking out may not show up on your browser sometimes, but that answer above was the first link shown for me when I typed "pyqt5 qthread signal" on the stackoverflow search bar and [pressed enter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pyqt5+qthread+signal).